# How to read PLY file format? Using non python

Tags: c++, file, decode, ply-file-format

I am currently trying to read/decode data from .PLY file. I can easly open file and read, but problem is with numeric data. File looks like this:

```html
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment Created by Blender 3.1.2 - www.blender.org
element vertex 1621
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property uchar alpha
element face 3130
property list uchar uint vertex_indices
end_header
7ë?Vý˝‹ĺ”>˙†J˙l$í?źÔ=ć$ľ>˙†J˙(çî?Yý˝ć$ľ>˙†J˙'Šč?[ý˝"6?˙†J˙KÓć?[YČ="6?˙†J˙…?Ů?[ý˝fË$?˙†J˙4Ą×?ĄŰŞ=fË$?˙†J˙ĚúĹ?[ý˝n8?˙†J˙r„Ä?s˛…=n8?˙†J˙Ôž°?[ý˝.2??˙†J˙?š?$>Í<n8?˙†J˙ÜB›?[ý˝n8?˙†J˙#ţ‡?[ý˝fË$?˙†J˙}ű†?eâ;fË$?˙†J˙gq?[ý˝"6?˙†J˙Ëšo?Đuő»"6?˙†J˙OÄ]?[ý˝_Yż>˙†J˙ľ\?P‰Ľ_Yż>˙†J˙: W?[ý˝ ÓS>˙†J˙JeU?@3ŁĽ ÓS>˙†J˙OÄ]?[ý˝Í#=˙†J˙ľ\?P‰ĽÍ#=˙†J˙gq?[ý˝eâ˝˙†J˙}ű†?eâ;š‡kľ˙†J˙#ţ‡?[ý˝š‡kľ˙†J˙ÜB›?[ý˝2   ťľ˙†J˙?š?$>Í<2 ťľ˙†J˙Ôž°?[ý˝\‘Şľ˙†J˙XPŻ?ţ9=\‘Şľ˙†J˙ĚúĹ?[ý˝2 ťľ˙†J˙4Ą×?ĄŰŞ=š‡kľ˙†J˙…?Ů?[ý˝š‡kľ˙†J˙KÓć?[YČ=eâ˝˙†J˙'Šč?[ý˝eâ˝˙†J˙(çî?Yý˝Ěp-=˙†J˙˘é?§ÍÍ=ąXô=˙†J˙ĽĚé?Uý˝ ÓS>˙†J˙$^ë?Wý˝ąXô=˙†J˙-{é?9‚Í=‹ĺ”>˙†J˙Ëâç?7ă§>ć$ľ>˙†J˙>ÜŇ?(“>fË$?˙†J˙Çi«?X>.2??˙†J˙XPŻ?ţ9=.2??˙†J˙˛¬–?¤/>n8?˙†J˙P÷?2Ŕ
>fË$?˙†J˙Ü<j?óÚ="6?˙†J˙zšP?5g¨= ÓS>˙†J˙:,W?S[µ=Í#=˙†J˙Ëšo?Đuő»eâ˝˙†J˙Ü<j?óÚ=eâ˝˙†J˙P÷?2Ŕ
>š‡kľ˙†J˙˛¬–?¤/>2  ťľ˙†J˙Ű&Ŕ?•¶€>2 ťľ˙†J˙r„Ä?s˛…=2 ťľ˙†J˙>ÜŇ?(“>š‡kľ˙†J˙µá?ÔËˇ>eâ˝˙†J˙l$í?źÔ=Ěp-=˙†J˙tä?á€¤>şXô=˙†J˙‡č?ÇĘ= ÓS>˙†J˙Nä?o[¤>‹ĺ”>˙†J˙ĺ5ß?×ź?ć$ľ>˙†J˙żBŮ??"6?˙†J˙µá?ÔËˇ>"6?˙†J˙öĘ?yř>fË$?˙†J˙Tň¸?Í3Ý>n8?˙†J˙Ű&Ŕ?•¶€>n8?˙†J˙°ů¤?îçľ>.2??˙†J˙‘?ś >n8?˙†J˙ľů}?dG…>fË$?˙†J˙@aa?š-_>"6?˙†J˙:,W?S[µ=_Yż>˙†J˙5O?˘SC>_Yż>˙†J˙®±H?Đş9> ÓS>˙†J˙5O?˘SC>Í#=˙†J˙@aa?š-_>eâ˝˙†J˙ľů}?dG…>š‡kľ˙†J˙‘?ś >2 ťľ˙†J˙Çi«?X>\‘Şľ˙†J˙°ů¤?îçľ>\‘Şľ˙†J˙Tň¸?Í3Ý>2 ťľ˙†J˙öĘ?yř>š‡kľ˙†J˙żBŮ??eâ˝˙†J˙Ëâç?7ă§>Ěp-=˙†J˙°çŰ?˙    ?ąXô=˙†J˙Uîâ?ˇ Ł> ÓS>˙†J˙ĂŰ?B ?‹ĺ”>˙†J˙>Ó?ÄÎ@?ć$ľ>˙†J˙±›Í?˛ä:?"6?˙†J˙tŔ?A®,?fË$?˙†J˙żŻ?ŤĹ?n8?˙†J˙ś?^ë?.2??˙†J˙t.‰?_"ć>n8?˙†J˙~=p?÷PÂ>fË$?˙†J˙)U?äĄ>"6?˙†J˙ĆC?
¤“>_Yż>˙†J˙kČ=?)ZŤ> ÓS>˙†J˙)U?äĄ>eâ˝˙†J˙~=p?÷PÂ>š‡kľ˙†J˙ś?^ë?\‘Şľ˙†J˙żŻ?ŤĹ?2    ťľ˙†J˙tŔ?A®,?š‡kľ˙†J˙±›Í?˛ä:?eâ˝˙†J˙ĺ5ß?×ź?Ěp-=˙†J˙ŔĐ?›…=?şXô=˙†J˙^pÚ?Q? ÓS>˙†J˙Á?+‡n?‹ĺ”>˙†J˙úĎ?@a=?‹ĺ”>˙†J˙(Ä?Ó·r?ć$ľ>˙†J˙uëľ?}k?"6?˙†J˙:z˘?S9D?n8?˙†J˙-ć?ő+?.2??˙†J˙'í^?ńű>fË$?˙†J˙ć5?ĺŠÂ>_Yż>˙†J˙m0?Űş> ÓS>˙†J˙ĆC?
```

I can read file, but I have no idea how to decode data below end_header line.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the format specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format))?

Comment: The data below the header is in binary format. The header tells you the structure of the binary data. In your case you have 1621 vertices. For each you have 3 `float`s (for x,y,z) and 4 `uchar`s (for r,g,b,a). Then you have 3130 faces, for each a `uchar` with the number of indices then `uint` per index.

Comment: The standard [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) library can read PLY files just fine.

Comment: My question is how to read this binary data in c++. I have char array and I don't know how to process it.